# htaccess: I want to permanantly remove the trailing slash from the end of my url

Tags: .htaccess

I do know that this is not the first time this question has been asked, but each case seems to be so specific to the context of that specific .htaccess file and I am having a hard time understanding this so far.

I'll start by just posting my .htaccess file here:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 http://mroberts.design/404

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mroberts\.design [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mroberts.design$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fcw\.mroberts\.design$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

**a)** I would like to remove the final trailing slash at the end of the url,

**b)** and I would like to remove the trailing slash before any query strings.

The way that I have this set up now, I don't see where I'm allowing there to be trailing slashes at all?

Help is appreciated.

---

EDIT:

Realistically the only part I care about removing the trailing slash from is this `^fcw\.mroberts\.design$` - that just has query strings like `?page=service` and etc, so the url ends up looking like `mroberts.design/?page=service`, I just want to remove that slash after `design` and before `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /example/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Two more options:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

If located in a directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. The htaccess file doesn't work if I throw that line in there, also not sure what to replace `example` with, tried a few things.

Comment: Realistically the only part I care about removing the trailing slash from is this `^fcw\.mroberts\.design$` - that just has query strings like `?page=service` and etc, so the url ends up looking like `mroberts.design/?page=service`, I just want to remove that slash after `design` and before `?`

Comment: See revised answer, might be more suitable.